# Python curses - resizing/scrolling the screen

Tags: python-3.x, scroll, resize, curses

I am creating a terminal-based RPG game. Recently, due to issues with the CMD (flickering when refreshing and other problems) I decided to move to curses.

I encountered issues with screen capacity during, say, long dialogues. In the CMD the screen just scrolled automatically - and that is what I am looking for.

My approach was as follows. I have a number of scripts containing classes and functions grouped according to functionality (such as ones pertaining to the board, to the player, NPCs, general utility functions script etc.). All of them also require access to some shared variables and objects; I group those in a shared.py script and subscribe the remaining scripts to it; the portion of that script relevant to the display mechanism looks like this:

```
shared.py

import curses
sc  = curses.initscr()
scr = curses.newpad(1000,1000)
scr.scrollok
```

And for refreshing I use:

```
shared.scr.refresh(0, 0, 0, 0, shared.sc.getmaxyx()[0] - 1, shared.sc.getmaxyx()[1] - 1)
```

But at the moment, when the display fills up, the new content is, I believe, still being dumped into the pad, but is not visible on the display. I could probably come up with a way of shifting the arguments of refresh() so that the bottom line of the display is always coincident with the most recent line added to the pad, but that still only gives me one screen's worth of visibility.

Is it possible to print the contents of the pad into the window in such a way so that the old contents are retained and accessible by scrolling up? Effectively, I want to be able to keep adding lines to my display and as it fills up, I want more display area to be generated and the old content that no longer fits inside the display to move out through the top edge of the display (but for it to still be accessible by scrolling).

Comment: That's what a *pad* is for: but your application has to manage the viewport (window) to show what you want from the *pad*.

Comment: I see. Is there a good way of returning the y-position of the most recently written line? There is getsyx() but I think that returns the position of the cursor on the display screen, not anything to do with the pad.

Comment: getyx's *window* parameter should work with a pad - but there's still the mapping from pad to viewport-window which the program has to work out...

Comment: EDIT: never mind, I now realized that there also exists a function called getyx() (without the 's') that can refer to the pad itself. As for mapping, I think I can solve that by playing with the refresh() function and writing some wrapper functions. Thanks!